# Method of characteristics-Hypebolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking at the following example of solving an hyperbolic system of equations using the method of characteristics:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{t}}+a \frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{x}}=0\\ 
\frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{t}}+b \frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{x}}=0
\end{matrix}\right\}$$

$a,b>0 \ ,  \ \ \ \displaystyle{u=u(u_1, u_2)} \ , \ \ \ A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a\\ 
b & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\displaystyle{u_t+Au_x=0}$

To check if it is hyperbolic, we have to find the eigenvalues:$\displaystyle{det(A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2-ab=0 \Rightarrow \lambda= \pm \sqrt{ab}}$

$\gamma=(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$

$\displaystyle{\gamma_1(\frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{t}}+a \frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{x}})+\gamma_2(\frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{t}}+b \frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{x}})=0}$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle{\gamma_1(\frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{b \gamma_2}{\gamma_1} \frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{x}})+\gamma_2(\frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{a \gamma_1}{\gamma_2} \frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{x}})=0}$

Since it should be in the form: $\gamma^T(u_t+\lambda u_x)=\gamma^T b$, it should be: $\displaystyle{\frac{b \gamma_2}{\gamma_1}=\lambda=\frac{a \gamma_1}{\gamma_2}}$

- $\lambda=\sqrt{ab}:$

We set $\displaystyle{\gamma_1=1}$, so $\displaystyle{\gamma_2= \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}$

$\displaystyle{(\frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{t}}+\sqrt{ab} \frac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial{x}})+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}(\frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{t}}+\sqrt{ab} \frac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial{x}})=0}$

$\displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2)+\sqrt{ab} \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2)=0}$

We set $\displaystyle{v_+=u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2}$. So we have: $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial{v_+}}{\partial{t}}+\sqrt{ab} \frac{\partial{v_+}}{\partial{x}}=0}$

The characteristic system is:
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{dv_+}{0}$$

$\displaystyle{v=\text{ constant }, v=u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2}$,  when $\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{ab}}$

$\displaystyle{x=\sqrt{ab}t+c \Rightarrow c=x- \sqrt{ab}t}$

$\displaystyle{v}$ is constant when $\displaystyle{x-\sqrt{ab}t}$ is constant.

That means that $$u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$

- $\lambda=-\sqrt{ab}:$

We conclude that $\displaystyle{v_-=u_1-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2= \text{ constant }}$ when $\displaystyle{x+\sqrt{ab}t}$ is constant.

$$u_1-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=\frac{g(x+\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$

$$\text{ So } u_1=f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)+g(x+\sqrt{ab}t) \text{ AND } u_2=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}[f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)-g(x+\sqrt{ab}t)]$$

---

Could you explain how we conclude that at the one case:
$$u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$
and at the other:
$$u_1-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=\frac{g(x+\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$
??
What are these functions $f$ and $g$??

Comment: In the future, please read the tag-wiki excerpts before using a tag. I've removed all of the inappropriate tags for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $g$ are "free functions". That is to say, for any pairs of functions $f$ and $g$ of one real variable, the pair
$$ \begin{align}
u_1(t,x) &= \frac14 \left( f(x - \sqrt{ab}t) + g(x + \sqrt{ab}t)\right) \\
u_2(t,x) &= \frac14 \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} \left( f(x - \sqrt{ab}t) - g(x+\sqrt{ab}t)\right) \end{align} $$
are solutions. (These two expressions are obtained by solving the ones you wrote near the end of your question.)

In actual applications, to determine the functions $f$ and $g$ you need to appeal to the initial conditions: you have
$$ \frac12 f(x) = u_1(x,0) + \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} u_2(x,0) $$
and similarly for $g(x)$, so the conditions given at $t = 0$ completely determines the functions $f$ and $g$.

---

As to how you arrive at the condition that $u_1 + \sqrt{\frac{a}b} u_2 = f/2$ etc.: this is the entire point of the method of characteristics. The method of characteristics tells you that, by examining the equation, you find $v_+$ to be a function that depends only on $c = x - \sqrt{ab}t$. Ditto for $v_-$. Now, naively an arbitrary function of $x$ and $t$ variables should have two degrees of freedom. The fact that $v_+$ depends only on $c = x-\sqrt{ab}t$ says that $v_+$ has only one degree of freedom, and so is really a "one dimensional" function in disguise.

Comment: I'm confused right now... $$"v_+ \text{ is constant when } x-\sqrt{ab}t \text{ is constant }"$$ means that $v_+$ depends on $x-\sqrt{ab}t$?? And why does this mean that $v_+$ is a function of $x-\sqrt{ab}t$??

Comment: Think about a function $F$ of two variables $F(z,w)$. If "$F$ is constant when $z$ is constant", that means that for any $w_1, w_2$, $F(z,w_1) = F(z,w_2)$, since $z$ is held fixed. This means that $F$ is _independent_ of $w$. Or that $F$ is really a function of $z$ alone.

Comment: Ok!!! I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)